# getting password requirements from server

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, openid-connect

Is there a standardized way (OpenId Connect or other wise) of getting password requirements to validate input client side, for example on account creation forms ect.?

Comment: Nope, OAuth 2.0 is authorisation and OpenID Connect is about authentication. These protocols does not define password requirements, their transmission methods

Comment: I'm not looking for the actual requirements. But like how OpenId Connect has .well-known/openid-configuration, is there a standard for presenting the requirements (dose not have to be openid or oauth)?